# Word for when something you are searching for is right next to you

Tags: single-word-requests

I suddenly remember that I have to call someone with my mobile phone, but then I think "where is it?" right before I notice that the phone is sitting next to my hand. I feel "wow, lucky"...

Is there an English word for a situation where the thing I am searching for is just next to my hand?

Comment: How about [handy](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/handy)?

Comment: If it was a snake, it would have bitten you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A common idiom used in this instance is the expression ["*right under one's nose,*"](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/in+front+of+very+eyes) where one [*overlooks*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/overlook) an object that's right in front of them. A similar idiom is ["right before one's very eyes."](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/before+very+eyes)

> Oh, there's my phone! It was right under my nose the whole time!

Answer (score 0):

> "It was hidden in plain {view / sight} [all along]!"